# Unable to process API data and decode into json swift in Xcode

Tags: swift

**Summary**

I am attempting to get data from an API and decode it into a json

I have 2 questions about the below code

1. is the output from apiOutput variable suitable to decode into a json format if not how do I get the correct output? I am thinking it might be changing the options in `JSONSerialization.jsonObject`
2. how do I feed my `apiOutput` variable to my PriceApiModel.swift which I am hoping is capable of decoding apiOutput into the correct json format. Even if PriceApiModel.swift is able to do this I am unsure how to feed apiOutput into it

This image is of the data the API is returning
[image: the API data]

My attempt at getting to the API data after its been called please see full code below

```
// from AppDelegate.swift full file included below
let apiOutput = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
print(apiOutput) // please see output below
```

Output from printing apiOutput

```
{
    askPrice = "0.07530300";
    askQty = "28.15780000";
    bidPrice = "0.07530200";
    bidQty = "20.99700000";
    closeTime = 1666814307216;
    count = 389744;
    firstId = 383543634;
    highPrice = "0.07593900";
    lastId = 383933377;
    lastPrice = "0.07530300";
    lastQty = "11.85740000";
    lowPrice = "0.07230700";
    openPrice = "0.07365100";
    openTime = 1666727907216;
    prevClosePrice = "0.07365200";
    priceChange = "0.00165200";
    priceChangePercent = "2.243";
    quoteVolume = "13084.96427533";
    symbol = ETHBTC;
    volume = "176432.41160000";
    weightedAvgPrice = "0.07416418";
}
```

I have made PriceApiModel.swift to try and decode the above output. However do not believe I have the right options in JSONSerialization because the output looks more like variables than a json file.

```
// PriceApiModel.swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct PriceApiModel: Hashable, Codable {
    var askPrice: String
    var askQty: String
    var bidPrice: String
    var bidQty: String
    var closeTime: Int
    var count: Int
    var firstId: Int
    var highPrice: String
    var lastId: Int
    var lastPrice: String
    var lastQty: String
    var lowPrice: String
    var openPrice: String
    var openTime: Int
    var prevClosePrice: String
    var priceChange: String
    var priceChangePercent: String
    var quoteVolume: String
    var symbol: String
    var volume: String
    var weightedAvgPrice: String

}
```

Full code of AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
    
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let headers = [
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "cannot provide this please see sample outpout",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "binance43.p.rapidapi.com"
    ]

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://binance43.p.rapidapi.com/ticker/24hr?symbol=ETHBTC")! as URL,
                                            cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                        timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        
    
    func getData() {
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error)
            } else {
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                do {
                    let apiOutput = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                        
                    
                        print(apiOutput) // this is the output I am getting
                                            
                } catch {
                    print("NOT WORKING ")
                }
            }
        })
        dataTask.resume()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Yes it’s suitable for using with Codable but if you want to use the price data in your app you should add a custome init(from:) and convert the properties to usable types like Decimal (or Double) and Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to decode the received data into your model you can use a `JSONDecoder`.

```
let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(PriceApiModel.self, from: data!)
```

But if you want to use this model further on in your code I would recommend using some usefull types for the data you recieve. I made an example for `askPrice` but the others would be done in a similar way.

```
// used for throwing errors
enum CustomError: Error{
    case decodingError
}

struct PriceApiModel: Hashable, Codable {
    //changed the String type to Decimal
    var askPrice: Decimal
    var askQty: String
    var bidPrice: String
    var bidQty: String
    var closeTime: Int
    var count: Int
    var firstId: Int
    var highPrice: String
    var lastId: Int
    var lastPrice: String
    var lastQty: String
    var lowPrice: String
    var openPrice: String
    var openTime: Int
    var prevClosePrice: String
    var priceChange: String
    var priceChangePercent: String
    var quoteVolume: String
    var symbol: String
    var volume: String
    var weightedAvgPrice: String
    
    // every property you are interested to decode needs a CodingKey.
    // You can omit values you are not interested in
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey{
        case askPrice
    }
    
    // here you decode your data into the struct
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // get the container
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        // decode the askPrice into a String and cast it into a Decimal
        let askPrice = Decimal(string: try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .askPrice))
        // check if casting was succesfull else throw
        guard let askPrice = askPrice else{
            throw CustomError.decodingError
        }
        // assign it
        self.askPrice = askPrice
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer the json decoder works perfectly which was my main issue. The only thing is with PriceApiModel it gives me the following error Extraneous argument label 'string:' in call remove string if I remove the string variable in ask price then I get this error Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String' likely I am not using the example correctly do you have any idears?

Comment: @carlwalters Hard to tell where the issue is without seeing the code. The example I posted works fine for me. Could you add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: your right its working I removed all the class variables apart from askPrice and it worked. Just to double check I need to add an enum coding key and a variable for each variable? Thank you

Comment: @carlwalters I would recommend decoding only those values you are interested in. If you do not need it just omit the variable and the CodingKey.