# Decoding 1957 Dictionaries from an array

Tags: json, swift, xcode, decoding

Goals

1. Accessing the Dictionaries within an array
2. Some how get all 1957 Dictionaries decoded without hand coding each ticker name.

The below image is data from https://rapidapi.com/Glavier/api/binance43/ to replicate the below image get Symbol Price Ticker needs to be selected.

[image]

With the help of another question which was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74213884/unable-to-process-api-data-and-decode-into-json-swift-in-xcode/74214481?noredirect=1#comment131039169_74214481) I have included code below which I am trying to change to accomplish the above goals.

CallApi.swift - this file calls the API and models it to PriceApiModel

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let headers = [
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "Sorry I cannot include this",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "binance43.p.rapidapi.com"
    ]

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://binance43.p.rapidapi.com/ticker/price")! as URL,
                                            cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                        timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        

    func getData() {
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("error")
            } else {
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                do {
                    //let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                    let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(PriceApiModel.self, from: data!)
                    
                    //print(String(model.symbol) + "name") // please see output below
                    //print(dictionary)
                } catch {
                    print("NOT WORKING ")
                }
            }
        })
        dataTask.resume()
        
    }
}
```

PriceApiModel.swift - I am trying to find a way for this file to be a model for decoding the data

```
struct PriceApiModel: Hashable, Codable {
    //changed the String type to Decimal
    var price: String

    // every property you are interested to decode needs a CodingKey.
    // You can omit values you are not interested in
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey{
        case askPrice
    }
    
    // here you decode your data into the struct
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // get the container
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        // decode the askPrice into a String and cast it into a Decimal
        let askPrice = String(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .askPrice))
        // check if casting was succesfull else throw
        guard let askPrice = askPrice else{
            throw CustomError.decodingError
        }
        // assign it
        self.askPrice = askPrice
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a custom `init(from:)`, what value does it add compared to the answer to your previous question that you linked to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just tried out what you want to achieve here. First of all, you declared a service class (fetching data) as ViewController, by inheritance a `UIViewController`. It seems to me a bit odd just having this in a class because the `UIViewController` is not used. Secondly, I would recommend you to watch or read something about `Codable` for example [Hackingforswift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/119/codable-cheat-sheet). It helped at least me :)

However, here is a Code that shows you a way how it could work:

`OptionalObject` is needed because of the data structure, holding everything within an array.

```swift
struct OptionalObject<Base: Decodable>: Decodable {
    public let value: Base?

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        do {
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            self.value = try container.decode(Base.self)
        } catch {
            self.value = nil
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct PriceApiModel: Codable {
    let price: String
    let symbol: String
}
```

```swift
enum ServiceError: Error {
    case failureAtDecoding
}
```

```swift
// MVVM Pattern https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/introducing-mvvm-into-your-swiftui-project
class ServiceViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // Publisher you can subscribe to it.
    // Every time the Publisher changes view will re-render.
    @Published var priceModel: [PriceApiModel] = []
    
    let headers = [
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "binance43.p.rapidapi.com"
    ]
    
    var request = URLRequest(
        url: URL(string: "https://binance43.p.rapidapi.com/ticker/price")!,
        cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
        timeoutInterval: 5.0
    )
    
    
    init() {
        self.getData { priceModel in
            // As DocC says:
            /// A value that represents either a success or a failure, including an
            // So you have to "unwrap" it to handle success or failure
            switch priceModel {
            case let .success(result):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.priceModel = result
                }
            case let .failure(failure):
                print(failure)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getData(priceModel: @escaping (Result<[PriceApiModel], Error>) -> Void) {
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                priceModel(.failure(error))
            } else if let data = data {
                let model = try? JSONDecoder().decode([OptionalObject<PriceApiModel>].self, from: data)
                
                let editModel = model?.compactMap {
                    PriceApiModel(price: $0.value?.price ?? "nil", symbol: $0.value?.symbol ?? "nil")
                }
                
                if let editModel = editModel {
                    priceModel(.success(editModel))
                } else {
                    priceModel(.failure(ServiceError.failureAtDecoding))
                }
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    // Initialize the ServiceViewModel as StateObject
    @StateObject var viewModel: ServiceViewModel = .init()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.priceModel, id: \.symbol) { model in
                    HStack {
                        Text(model.symbol)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Text(model.price)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Hope I could help.

Comment: Thank you very much this was extremely helpful and its all working. I just had one question in func getData() do you know how I can return variable model as a dict I have attempted to put getData function to return type -> PriceApiModel and returned model but I couldn't figure out how to return it?

Comment: I have also attempted to return dataTask if I print it I get the following LocalDataTask <2B29207A-4F36-42A7-828B-467603D7B5C4> do you know how I could unpack this into a dict?

Comment: @carlwalters I edit my first post, I hope that is what you meant.

Comment: The edit you kindly did appears to be what I am looking for however when I call the getData function in the UI it gives me the following error "Missing argument for parameter 'priceModel' in call" I have tried putting a number of things as a parameter sorry if this is a silly question but what should I feed it as a parameter? I very much appreciate your help

Comment: inside body of the UI I have put          Button("working") {
                api.getData()  { priceModel in
                    var firstValue = priceModel[0]
                } Above is my attempt to get the first value from the priceModel dict I also attempted a for loop to open it up. I just wanted to double check that priceModel is a dict? Thank you

Comment: Hi again ;) you have to unwrap the result you can not access it via an index. Because a Result has a Success and a Failure. You can unwrap it via If case or via switch. I will edit my previous post again. hope that helps... - I assuming you working with Swiftui

Comment: You went way above and beyond the original question, I cannot tell you how helpful this has been to see how this works with your example. Thanks again Carl